# modifying ggplot objects after creation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a preferred way to modify `ggplot` objects after creation?

For example I recommend my students to save the r object together with the pdf file for later changes...

```
library(ggplot2)
graph <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=qsec, fill=cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars))) +
  xlab('miles per galon') +
  ggtitle('my title')

ggsave('test.pdf', graph)
save(graph, file='graph.RData')
```

So new, in case they have to change title or labels or sometimes other things, they can easily load the object and change simple things.

```
load('graph.RData')
print(graph)
graph + 
  ggtitle('better title') +
  ylab('seconds per quarter mile')
```

What do I have to do for example to change the colour to discrete scale? In the original plot I would wrap the `y` in `as.factor`. But is there a way to do it afterwards? 
Or is there a better way on modifying the objects, when the data is `gone`. Would love to get some advice.

Comment: You could look at Rcolorbrewer package. I did it a couple of times, where I would make the plot, store it as an object and when finally when I am building a report using many objects like above, I would use color brewer and change the color scheme.

Comment: If you have saved the plot object the data is not really gone (have a look at `str(graph))`, so you could redo the plot using `ggplot(graph$data, aes(...` , , or you may be able to update the mapping ie `graph$mapping$fill <- quote(factor(cyl))`

Answer (score 53):

You could use `ggplot_build()` to alter the plot without the code or data:

Example plot:

```
data("iris")

p <- ggplot(iris) + 
  aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species) + 
  geom_point()
```

Colours are respective to `Species`.

Disassemble the plot using `ggplot_build()`:

```
q <- ggplot_build(p)
```

Take a look at the object `q` to see what is happening here.
To change the colour of the point, you can alter the respective table in `q`:

```
q$data[[1]]$colour <- "black"
```

Reassemble the plot using `ggplot_gtable()`:

```
q <- ggplot_gtable(q)
```

And plot it:

```
plot(q)
```

Now, the points are black.

Comment: This is a really useful answer. However, do you know what it would take to turn q back into the same object as the original ggplot. Currently, this is incompatible with things like +ggsave() and +ggtitle(), which would be really nice to add on to q

Comment: @jntrcs Currently you can do: `q = ggplot_build(ggplot_plot)` `q$data[[1]]$size = 0.2` `q = ggplot_gtable(q)` `ggsave(filename, plot=q)` to save the edited plot. (just pointing it out since no one did in 2 years)