# Remove geom(s) from an existing ggplot chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand how I can make changes to the internals of a ggplot2 chart. I started reading the few ressources I could find about `ggplot_built` and `ggplot_gtable`, but I could not answer the question below.

Given a plot `g` with 2 `geom`.

```
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=Sepal.Width))
g
```

[image]

Is there a way to dive into the `g` object and remove one/multiple geoms?

Can I get, starting from `g`, a plot with no geoms?

[image]

Or with just the `geom_text` removed?

[image]

---

### **UPDATE after more thorough testing of the answers**

I just noticed that removing geoms can have an impact on the layout of the other geoms. Probably great as a default and the intended behaviour for most use cases, but I actually need the exact same chart "layout" (axis and positions of remaining geoms).

Example, before removing one geom:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
count(mpg, class) %>%
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(class, pct)) +
  geom_col(fill="blue") +
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_point(size=4)
```

[image]

after removing one geom (note that the y axis doesn't start at 0 anymore, I guess the default behaviour for line/point without bars):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
count(mpg, class) %>%
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(class, pct)) +
  geom_col(fill="blue") +
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_point(size=4) -> p
p$layers[[1]] <- NULL
p
```

[image]

Any ways to force ggplot to keep the exact same layout?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can access / manipulate `g`'s elements the way you would do with other `R` object.

```
g$layers
#[[1]]
#geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#position_identity 

#[[2]]
#mapping: label = Sepal.Width 
#geom_text: parse = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE
#stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#position_identity
```

Remove `geom_text`:

```
g$layers[[2]] <- NULL
```

Remove all `layers`

```
g$layers <- NULL
g
```

[image]

---

The `gginnards` package offers some functions to manipulate `ggplot` layers, see the vignette [User Guide: 4 Manipulation of plot layers](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gginnards/vignettes/user-guide-2.html) for details.

---

**edit**

Following the question of [How can I extract plot axes' ranges for a ggplot2 object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705345/how-can-i-extract-plot-axes-ranges-for-a-ggplot2-object) I came to a solution that uses `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable`. The idea is simply to copy the layout parameters taken from `ggplot_built(p)` to the new plot, for which we deleted a layer.

```
# create a copy of p
p_new <- p

# delete the first layer
p_new$layers[[1]] <- NULL
p_new_build <- ggplot_build(p_new)

# this is the important line
p_new_build$layout$panel_params <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p, ggplot_gtable(p_new_build), ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use [gginnards](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gginnards/vignettes/user-guide-2.html) package to make life easier

```r
library(ggplot2)

### sample plot w/ both points and labels
g <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = Sepal.Width))
g
```

[image]

```r
### https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gginnards/vignettes/user-guide-2.html
library(gginnards)

### remove points
delete_layers(g, "GeomPoint")
```

[image]

```r
### remove text
delete_layers(g, "GeomText")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the demo!

Comment: @Tung As of version 0.3.0 the `which_layer` function is no longer part of `ggpmisc` but of the new package [`gginnards`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gginnards/). Best

Answer (score 4):

You can try to include some alpha. Instead of removing the layer, it will not show up.

```
count(mpg, class) %>%
  mutate(pct=n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(class, pct)) +
  geom_col(fill="blue", alpha=0) +
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_point(size=4)
```

[image]

You can of course add the alpha afterwards like

```
p <- ggplot_build(p)
p$data[[1]]$alpha <- 0
plot(ggplot_gtable(p))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you add it on a per geom basis on an existing chart object?

Comment: I should do my homework better: this was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940643/2008527

Something like: `ggplot_build(p) -> q; q$data[[1]]$alpha <- 0; plot(ggplot_gtable(q))`

Comment: Also found that you need to apply `p$data[[1]]$size <- 0` to remove things like the border of GeomCol...

Answer (score 1):

Build the plot to have all the `waiver()` stuff (axis limits and labels, etc.) resolve, tamper with that, then convert it to a `gtable` for plotting.

```
p_built <- ggplot_build(p)
p_built$plot$layers[[1]] <- NULL
p_built$data[[1]] <- NULL
plot(ggplot_gtable(p_built))
```

Note that you need to remove not only the layer but also the dataset for that layer.