# Translating colors to linetypes/symbols in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose some R package produces a `ggplot` object, `g`, that includes points and/or lines of different colors. But suppose you need to produce this in suitable form for black-and-white reproduction where the colors don't show.

One possibility is to print `g + scale_color_grey()`. However, different gray-scale values are not easy to discriminate, and even grayscale is not always suitable for some forms of reproduction.

Is there a way to somehow map `color` groupings to `linetype` (and also to `shape`)? I could not figure out how to do this.

For an example to mess with, try

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:3, 1:3), y = c(4, 1, 9, 2, 7, 5), 
                 trt = factor(c(1,1,1, 2,2,2)))
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group = trt, color = trt)) + 
     geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Given `g`, make a suitable B/W plot with different point shapes and line types. *This needs to be done without changing the code that produced `g`.*

Comment: Do you know that you grouped/colored by `trt` or are you hoping to extract that information out of the `g` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** @aosmith's answer in the comments is most compact:

```
g + 
  aes(linetype = trt, shape = trt) + 
  scale_color_grey(start = 0, end = 0) + 
  theme_bw()
```

**Original**
You can use the `linetype` and `shape` arguments in `aes()`, and remove the `color` argument in the initial call to `ggplot()` for b&w.

If you can't change `g`, use `scale_color_manual` to set the lines to black, then `theme_bw()` to create the b&w layout.

```
g +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = trt), size = 1) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = trt), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I knew right after I posted the question that I should have emphasized *without changing `g`*. The context is that some R package produced `g` -- I can't change it, I have to work with it.

Comment: Ok, in that case, use `scale_color_manual()` in addition to the `aes` adjustments.  See updated answer.

Comment: I won't believe you until you first produce `g` exactly as I did, then add stuff to `g`.

Comment: You don't have to believe me, just try it.  I can add updated code but it's literally just copy and pasting.

Comment: I did try it. `g + scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "black")) + theme_bw()` gave me two black solid lines with round dots.

Comment: You didn't add the second round of `geom_point` and `geom_line`

Comment: There are also a few strategies for removing `ggplot` layers, although I haven't done that here.  See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434608/remove-geoms-from-an-existing-ggplot-chart).

Comment: Note you don't have to add extra layers if the given aesthetics are global.  You can do something like `g + aes(linetype = trt, shape = trt)` to add aesthetic mappings without putting a new, e.g., points layer on top of the old one (although you would want to add new layers if you were adding additional layer-specific changes like the `size`).

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. `g + aes(linetype = trt, shape = trt) + scale_color_grey(start = 0, end = 0) + theme_bw()` does it all.

Comment: Really nice @aosmith, I learned something new.  Adding to answer now.