# How to change type of line in prophet plot?

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

Facebook's Prophet in R (there's also a Python version) is used to generate time series forecasts.

A model `m` is created by:

```
m <- prophet(df)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
plot(m, forecast)
```

Which returns a very nicely formatted graph, like:

[image]

I would like to change the line type, to get not dots but a usual thin line.

I had tried this

```
lines(m$history$y,lty=1)
```

but got an error

```
 In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
```

Are there are any suggestions how to convert those dots into a line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot` method for `prophet` objects uses `ggplot2`, so base R graphics functions like `lines()` won't work.  You can use `ggplot2::geom_line()` to *add* lines, but at the moment I don't see an easy way to *replace* the points by lines ...

Example from `?prophet`:

```
history <- data.frame(ds = seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2016-01-01'), by = 'd'),
                           y = sin(1:366/200) + rnorm(366)/10)
     m <- prophet(history)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 365)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
pp <- plot(m,forecast)
```

Add lines:

```
library(ggplot2)
pp + geom_line()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940000/modifying-ggplot-objects-after-creation) provides a (hacky) way forward:

```
pp2 <- pp + geom_line()
qq2 <- ggplot_build(pp2)
qq2$data[[2]]$colour <- NA
plot(ggplot_gtable(qq2))
```

[image]

But obviously something went wrong with the hack.  The better bet would be to look at the plot method(`prophet:::plot.prophet`) and modify it to behave as you want ... Here is the bare-bones version:

```
df <- prophet:::df_for_plotting(m, forecast)
gg <-ggplot(df, aes(x = ds, y = y)) + labs(x = "ds", y = "y")
gg <- gg + geom_ribbon(ggplot2::aes(ymin = yhat_lower, 
        ymax = yhat_upper), alpha = 0.2, fill = "#0072B2", 
        na.rm = TRUE)
## replace first geom_point() with geom_line() in next line ...
gg <- gg + geom_line(na.rm = TRUE) + geom_line(aes(y = yhat), 
    color = "#0072B2", na.rm = TRUE) + theme(aspect.ratio = 3/5)
```

I may have stripped out some components that exist in your data/forecast, though ...

[image]

Comment: many thanks, but is it possible to make such manipulations with `dyplot.prophet(m, forecast)` (html version of plot) ?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to make such manipulations with `dyplot.prophet(m, forecast)` (html version of plot) :) before that, we should rewrite function like here:

```
dyplot.prophet <- function(x, fcst, uncertainty=TRUE, 
                           ...) 
{
  forecast.label='Predicted'
  actual.label='Actual'
  # create data.frame for plotting
  df <- prophet:::df_for_plotting(x, fcst)

  # build variables to include, or not, the uncertainty data
  if(uncertainty && exists("yhat_lower", where = df))
  {
    colsToKeep <- c('y', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper')
    forecastCols <- c('yhat_lower', 'yhat', 'yhat_upper')
  } else
  {
    colsToKeep <- c('y', 'yhat')
    forecastCols <- c('yhat')
  }
  # convert to xts for easier date handling by dygraph
  dfTS <- xts::xts(df %>% dplyr::select_(.dots=colsToKeep), order.by = df$ds)

  # base plot
  dyBase <- dygraphs::dygraph(dfTS)

  presAnnotation <- function(dygraph, x, text) {
    dygraph %>%
      dygraphs::dyAnnotation(x, text, text, attachAtBottom = TRUE)
  }

  dyBase <- dyBase %>%
    # plot actual values
    dygraphs::dySeries(
      'y', label=actual.label, color='black',stepPlot = TRUE, strokeWidth=1
    ) %>%
    # plot forecast and ribbon
    dygraphs::dySeries(forecastCols, label=forecast.label, color='blue') %>%
    # allow zooming
    dygraphs::dyRangeSelector() %>% 
    # make unzoom button
    dygraphs::dyUnzoom()
  if (!is.null(x$holidays)) {
    for (i in 1:nrow(x$holidays)) {
      # make a gray line
      dyBase <- dyBase %>% dygraphs::dyEvent(
        x$holidays$ds[i],color = "rgb(200,200,200)", strokePattern = "solid")
      dyBase <- dyBase %>% dygraphs::dyAnnotation(
        x$holidays$ds[i], x$holidays$holiday[i], x$holidays$holiday[i],
        attachAtBottom = TRUE)
    }
  }
  return(dyBase)
}
```

the `strokeWidth=0` was before and we have changed it to `strokeWidth=1` and added `stepPlot = TRUE`

the whole basis code is situated here: https://rdrr.io/cran/prophet/src/R/plot.R