# Mass testing of uniqueness with testthat

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I have a package with automated tests using testthat. However, I am wondering what the best practice is when one wants to have a lot of tests. One common situation is that I am testing that all the arguments/pars do something unique. Here's a non-functional example to give an idea:

```
# GG_heatmap --------------------------------------------------------------

#save plots to list
heatmaps = list(
  #various options
  default = mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)] %>% GG_heatmap(),
  no_reorder = mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)] %>% GG_heatmap(reorder_vars = F),
  no_values = mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)] %>% GG_heatmap(add_values = F),
  many_digits = mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)] %>% GG_heatmap(digits = 5)
)

test_that("GG_heatmap", {
  #check that plots work
  walk(heatmaps, ~expect_s3_class(., class = "ggplot"))

  #check for non-identity
  #cant think of an easy smart way to do this
  expect_true(!identical(heatmaps$default, heatmaps$no_reorder))
  expect_true(!identical(heatmaps$default, heatmaps$no_values))
  expect_true(!identical(heatmaps$default, heatmaps$many_digits))
  expect_true(!identical(heatmaps$no_reorder, heatmaps$no_values))
  expect_true(!identical(heatmaps$no_reorder, heatmaps$many_digits))
  expect_true(!identical(heatmaps$no_values, heatmaps$many_digits))
})
```

So, there is a function called `GG_heatmap()` (which is [this one](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization), modified a bit) that returns a `ggplot2` plot.

In the `walk()`, we merely check whether the class is right. I tried and it does fail appropriately when the class is wrong, and the summary of tests when executing `devtools::test()` is correct, i.e. it figures out that the `walk()` call runs 4 tests, not 1.

In the 6 tests below, I check that each plot object is different, i.e. the arguments do something, all of which is different from each other. In my case, since I have 4 versions, I need to test 6 (i.e., `choose(4, 2)`) combinations to ensure they are all unique. If I had, say, 10 arguments to test, this would be a lot of manual code to write (`choose(10, 2)` = 45).

So my question is, what are the best practices when doing tests like this? Is there a function that allows one to test each object for uniqueness? The best I can think of it looping over the output of:

```
> gtools::combinations(4, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    2    4
[6,]    3    4
```

and then calling on each row:

```
expect_true(!identical(heatmaps[[v1]], heatmaps[[v2]]))
```

where `v1` and `v2` refer to the integers in the columns above.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case I would say that - no matter how you finally implement them - these tests have little value and their results may even be not trustworthy.

The tests have little value, because if they pass you will still have very limited information: You will know that all the heatmaps look different (well, maybe, see below), but you will not know if they look the way you expect them to look.  However, despite the weak result, the test is likely to take a significant time, which will even grow heavily when additional heatmap styles get added.

The tests may not be trustworthy with respect to their limited information: Depending on the way ggplot works, even identically looking heatmaps may not compare equal, for example if the tool adds some time stamp to each generated heat map.  Even if the tool does not work like this today, you probably have no guarantee about this for the future.  Thus, even if your tests pass, some diagrams could still *look* the same, but compare non-equal.

Whether the heatmaps look the way you want them to look, certainly, is something you can not figure out with unit-testing.  Instead, you need to look at the resulting output - a test that would probably best be classified as a system-test.

Comment: One can deconstruct the properties of `ggplot`s to see if they have the correct layers etc. (using `ggplot_build()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41940643/3980197), so it is possible to do more exact tests of this nature, but it would require more coding to set up. In my case, just knowing they produce different results is good enough for me (this is my private package, not something where lots of $$$ depends on the results).

Comment: I see - then, if also the performance is not an issue for you, I would say your approach is fine.  Should performance become an issue at some point in time, you might then consider building some hash value for each plot and instead of pairwise comparison of the plots, compare the hashes.