# make color of one category grey in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to make this one group "unknown" grey and have a grey key in the legend

```
data <- fread(data_path)
bgrd <- data[data$pop == 'Unknown',]
ref <- data[data$pop != 'Unknown',]
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, fill=pop))
p <- p + geom_point(data=bgrd,  color='grey')
p <- p +  geom_point(data=ref, color='black', pch=21)
```

gives me this:
[image]

Close, but "unknown" is pink not grey in legend. What am I missing?

more of a reproducible examples:

```
bgrd <- iris[iris$Species == 'virginica',]
ref <- iris[iris$Species != 'virginica',]
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, fill=Species))
p <- p + geom_point(data=bgrd, color='grey')
p <- p + geom_point(data=ref, color='black', pch=21)
```

Comment: Try `scale_fill_manual(values = list_of_colors) #Where list_of_colors can be strings for colors or  hexadecimal definition` - you won't need to split the data between unknow and not unknow while you will set the colors for every group as you want. Only problem about scale_fill_manual() is you have to define colors for every group. Also, you can use several times the symbol + for ggplot instead of allocating 3 times a value in p.

Comment: Good tip, I knew about the `scale_fill_manual(values = list_of_colors)`, I was hoing for an automated solution where  "unknown" is always grey and the others follow default ggplot colors. Thanks for much though!

Comment: I thought about that but I don't know a specific function for that and without an data example I can't try to guess.

Comment: @RobertoT sorry, I added a reproducible  example

Comment: I'm now thrilled by get this, but I can't. I tried disassembling with `ggplot_build()` editing the colour or fill for the 5th colour group - which is "#E76BF3" - to "gray" and reassembling it with `ggplot_gtable()` but i can't find a specific property for the legend and its colours. Try to play with it, to see the properties of the plot after using ggplot_build you can write: `ggplot_build(<plot_name>)[[1]]`

Comment: Here you can find more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940000/modifying-ggplot-objects-after-creation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example solution (based on the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin)) for automatically assigning the color to a reference factor level. This example, however, does not adjust the PCH. This also assumes the grouping variable is a factor.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)


ref = "virginica"
myColors <- brewer.pal(length(levels(iris$Species)),"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(iris$Species)
myColors[names(myColors)==ref] <- "grey"
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "grp",values = myColors)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species))+
  geom_point()+
  colScale
```

[image]