# Making a graph connecting points with each other

Tags: r, plot

Does anyone know how to plot the following plot:

[image]

For more detail:
The dots show the combinations in which the variables (K,Q,W...) were tested with each other. I dont know the code to plot this graph. Can anyone help me here?

I'm very new to Rstudio and don't know the code to plot my data the way I want to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this would be possible in base R. I recommend recreating your dataset manually and then use `pivot_longer()` so your data is tidy enough for `ggplot()`. (Also, this kind of figure would probably be easy enough to recreate in PowerPoint if you wanted to go that route.)

```
library(tidyverse)
letter <- c("K", "Q", "W", "Z")
x1 <- c(1, 1, 0, 0)
x2 <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
x3 <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
x4 <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
x5 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(letter, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -letter) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  mutate(letter = factor(letter, levels = c("Z", "W", "Q", "K"))) 
  # mutating into a factor orders the `letter` variable so the letters are in your preferred order

# make your color palette
# based off here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70099073/make-color-of-one-category-grey-in-ggplot
mycolors <- c("green", "red", "yellow", "blue", "purple")
names(mycolors) <- levels(df$name)
color_scale <- scale_color_manual(name = "grp", values = mycolors)

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = letter)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = name, group = name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = name), size = 6) + 
  color_scale +
  theme_void() + # very blank ggplot2 theme
  theme(legend.position = "none") + # turn off legend
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black")) # color the yaxis tick marks
```

[image]