# ggplot2 function with unintended recursive sizing and overwriting of original plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to edit the size of different elements in gglot2 objects, for instance making the points bigger. I need to work on already constructed objects: i.e., I am given a ggplot2 object test_plot and I want to make a function that enables me to scale the point sizes and return a **new** ggplot2 object. I need both plot objects: the original (with un-scaled elements) and the new plot with scaled elements.

However, my attempts below seem to scale both the original and new plots - leading to recursive scaling when called multiple times. I am not familiar with this behavior in R.

I thought everything in the function was locally scoped and wouldn't touch the original plot in the global environment.

```r
library(ggplot2)
test_plot = ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg, x = hp), col = "black")

adjust_point_size <- function(gg_plot,element_size_adjust = 1) {
  build_data =  ggplot_build(gg_plot)$data
  point_size = unique(build_data[[1]]$size)

  gg_plot$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- point_size*element_size_adjust
  gg_plot
}

adjust_point_size(gg_plot = test_plot, element_size_adjust = 2) # ok
```

[image]

```r
adjust_point_size(gg_plot = test_plot, element_size_adjust = 2) # why doubled
```

[image]

```r
adjust_point_size(gg_plot = test_plot, element_size_adjust = 2) # why doubled again
```

[image]

```r
test_plot # why different?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I tried saving the plot object as a new temporary object within the function, e.g., test_plot2 = test_plot and then working on test_plot2. I didn't expect this to work (and it didn't).

I am using ggplot2 v3.4.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does this work?

```
adj_pt_size <- function(ggplot, size_adj) {
  ggplot$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- 1*size_adj
  return(ggplot)
}

test_plot = ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg, x = hp), col = "black")

adj_pt_size(test_plot, 2)
```

Comment: Can someone explain the differences in this vs OPs function definitions that made it work?

Comment: I think the op's issue was that `point_size*element_size_adjust` was stacking every time they ran the function, so I replaced it with `1*element_size_adjust` to avoid that issue

Comment: This works for me! Thanks. Still unsure why the original didn't work, e.g.,  wanted to extract the size of the original (if it wasn't 1) and then scale that up. Anyway I can work with this

Comment: Where exactly does it "stack", because I thought as well that everything stays inside the function scope?

Comment: In fact, this solution is no better than op's: after running the function, the plot object is permanently altered. (e.g.: `adj_pt_size(test_plot, 5)` and then run `test_plot`)

Comment: Yes, the fundamental issue with the op function was that it altered the underlying ggplot, my original solution didn't change that fact, it was just a workaround to avoid it stacking every time the function was run. I think the new solution below works without changing the original plot, but if you more than one layer, it needs a bit of extra fiddling

Answer (score 0):

Although it's more complicated, and the original answer worked for the op's purpose, here's a slightly more complicated version that I think does exactly what the op wanted. If the plot has more than one layer, you'll need to adjust the function to duplicate and edit the desired layer(s).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggedit)

test_plot = ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg, x = hp), col = "black")

adjust_point_size <- function(gg_plot, element_size_adjust = 1) {
  build_data =  ggplot_build(gg_plot)$data
  point_size = unique(build_data[[1]]$size)
  
  new_root <- cloneRoot(gg_plot)
  new_layer <- cloneLayer(gg_plot[["layers"]][[1]])
  
  new_plot <- new_root + new_layer
  new_plot$layers[[1]]$aes_params$size <- point_size*element_size_adjust
  new_plot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [modifying ggplot objects after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940000/modifying-ggplot-objects-after-creation), I got to this solution.

What makes this work?

- one key is to manipulate point size inside the `data` list instead of `layers`.
- Getting a pre-assembled ggplot via `ggplot_build()`, then manipulate it. Finish assembly via `ggplot_gtable()`

```
require(ggplot2)

adj_pt_size <- function(gg_plot, element_size_adjust) {
  
  q <- ggplot_build(gg_plot)

  q$data[[1]]$size <- 
    q$data[[1]]$size * element_size_adjust
  
  return(plot(ggplot_gtable(q)))
}

adj_pt_size(gg_plot = test_plot, element_size_adjust = 10) # ok
```